# How to CUT xx second every yy second and loop till the end in video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, cut

I hope someone support me, this is my question:
How to CUT xx second every yy second and loop till the end in video with ffmpeg?

Comment: Can you clarify what "*loop till the end*" means?

Comment: Hello @Gyan,
I will take an example for you to understand:
I have a 10 minute video,
Every 30 seconds I will cut off 5 seconds, repeated until the end of the video.
Hope your help!